# Как в функцию angular передать значение атрибута?

Tags: jquery, javascript, angularjs

Допустим, у меня есть ссылка:

```
a data-pressed="false" ng-click="func(...)"
```

Как в `func` передать значение `data-pressed`?

Comment: @alexsemen1994, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Каким образом вы будете в функции клика использовать true или false? Или вы хотите настроить, будет работать функция по клику или нет?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае - никак.

Вместо передачи атрибута, стоит передавать параметр напрямую:

```
a  ng-click="func(false)"
```

Тоже самое работает, если для значения атрибута использовалось выражение ангуляра

```
a  ng-click="func(expression)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно вот так:

```
data-pressed="false" ng-click="func($(this).data('pressed'))"
```

Comment: это не сработает, потому что в `ng-click` передается выражение ангуляра, в нем `this` - это не элемент, а `scope`, кроме того все функции и переменные в разметке берутся из scope, и  если в нем нет свойства `$` - то глобальная переменная `$` не будет спользована